# WindowsSdkDir is not set correctly in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, winapi

I'm attempting to build some C++ code that requires the Windows 7.0 SDK header files and libraries. My VC++ Directories is set to:

```
$(VCInstallDir)include
$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include
$(WindowsSdkDir)\include
$(WindowsSdkDir)\common\include
$(FrameworkSDKDir)include
```

My `$(WindowsSdkDir)` variable *should* be set to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\` -- I've used the SDK's "Visual Studio Registration" configuration tool to set it, and it looks correct in the registry. I've checked under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows` (and the same in `Wow6432Node`.

Despite this, Visual C++ is still picking up header files from `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\`

What's wrong, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ah. Found this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/windowssdk/archive/2008/06/30/winsdk-bug-notification-sdk-config-tool-appears-to-work-but-fails.aspx

Essentially, the configuration tool only updates the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE settings; Visual Studio uses the HKEY_CURRENT_USER settings in preference.

Comment: Just had a similar problem.  Windows SDK v7.0A was installed but only found in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` registry key and not in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.  VS was using the Windows SDK v6.0A instead since it was registered in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. One way to fix the problem is to use the `reg copy HKLM\... HKCU\... /s` command to copy the data over, and then to fix the `CurrentVersion` and `CurrentInstallFolder` values to use the newer SDK.

Comment: The link in the answer talks about version 6.1 of Windows SDK yet you had a problem with version 7.0. Does it mean Microsoft hasn't fixed the bug in Windows SDK 7.0 although they had discovered it in earlier version (6.1)?

Comment: [How to get the WinSDK Configuration Tool to work](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowssdk/archive/2008/10/06/how-to-get-the-winsdk-configuration-tool-to-work.aspx) covers yet another problem with WinSDK Configuration Tool this time due to the bug in Service Pack 1 for Visual Studio 2008 Retail (not Express).

Comment: Link in answer no longer... links. Here is corrected link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/7d0eafe5-477b-40cc-85a1-cd6296c6b745/winsdk-bug-notification-sdk-config-tool-appears-to-work-but-fails

Answer (score 8):

I came across this same problem and found a solution which seems better than hacking around with the registry...

"Open any project and change the Platform Toolset to Windows7.1SDK and build it. After this, the macro $(WindowsSdkDir) changes for all projects to v7.1 regardless of the selected Platform Toolset."

It worked for me.

Comment: This (presumably) applies to VS2010. When I asked the question, we were still using VS2008. So, this update is useful. Thanks.

Comment: Just wanted to add the explicit instructions:  select your project, then select Properties-->Configuration Properties-->General.

Answer (score 3):

I had a lot of linker errors in Visual Studio 2008 Express which I suspected were related to the issues being discussed in this question and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15053337/1243435). After a lot of investigating I managed to fix the problem, and thought it would be useful to share the knowledge.

In summary (I give more detail below):

- the linker errors were happening because the value of `%WindowsSdkDir%` was not being set correctly, and therefore VS could not find files like `kernel32.lib`,
- the reason for the incorrect setting was frustratingly simple: a space had crept into the `PATH` variable just at the front of the `%SystemRoot%\system32` entry,
- this meant that the `reg query` MSDOS command had effectively been disabled,
- this command is used in one of the VS batch files to set variable values; the batch file therefore ended up setting `%WindowsSdkDir%` not from the registry (all my registry entries were correct), but instead set it to equal its default value of `%VCINSTALLDIR%\PlatformSDK\` which was not correct for my setup.

Obviously, the fix was easy in my case: remove the space! But of course, it is the route to the solution that really is the interesting bit...

As I said, the first symptom of the problem was that VS was giving nasty linker errors. I was able to understand from these that VS was not able to find files like `kernel32.lib`.

If you search around this you are likely to find yourself at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15053337/1243435). The answer that currently sits with the most votes mentions `WindowsSdkDir`, and suggests that the questioner check it is correctly referenced in the VS settings.

It was clear to me that my VS settings were not the problem because I had already been able to get my installation completed error free on another machine. More searching on 'WindowsSdkDir' led me to this here SO question, and I checked all the registry entries that are suggested (here and elsewhere):

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows`
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6342Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows`
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Wow6342Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows`

All of these were correctly set: the value in the registry of the `CurrentInstallFolder` value was always `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\`. I was at a loss to understand why the `%WindowsSdkDir%` variable was being set with a yet different value.

Yet more searching led me to places like [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d52dcdd3-0ab4-4c0a-a0f4-91c30f8e00d3/in-visual-studio-command-prompts-batch-fiel-i-see-dp0binvcvars32bat-what-does-dp0bin?forum=vssetup), and I felt ready to have a go at understanding how the `%WindowsSdkDir%` variable gets set.

My best understanding of the process is:

- The file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat` is the one of the first scripts to get run. (BTW you right-click and `Edit` to see its contents). It was not difficult to work out that the line `call "%~dp0bin\vcvars32.bat"` is executed.
- The `%~dp0bin\` is interpreted as 'the `bin` directory in the current directory`, and therefore the next place to go is there.
- In that `bin` directory there is the expected `vcvars32.bat`, and it contains only one command: `"%VS90COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat"`.
- To see what `%VS90COMNTOOLS%` means you can open the Visual Studio command prompt (which you find in the Start Menu in the VS section) and enter `echo %VS90COMNTOOLS%`. For me it expands to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools`.
- So I find myself at the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\vcvars32.bat`. This file has some real content, and I was able to recognize that the command `@call :GetWindowsSdkDir` is where the action happens.
- That function is defined in this same file, a few lines down:

  ```
  :GetWindowsSdkDir
  @call :GetWindowsSdkDirHelper HKLM > nul 2>&1
  @if errorlevel 1 call :GetWindowsSdkDirHelper HKCU > nul 2>&1
  @if errorlevel 1 set WindowsSdkDir=%VCINSTALLDIR%\PlatformSDK\
  @exit /B 0
  ```
- This function obviously depends on a second function in that same file:

  ```
  :GetWindowsSdkDirHelper
  @for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%i in ('reg query "%1\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows" /v "CurrentInstallFolder"') DO (
      if "%%i"=="CurrentInstallFolder" (
          SET "WindowsSdkDir=%%k"
      )
  )
  @if "%WindowsSdkDir%"=="" exit /B 1
  @exit /B 0
  ```

We are nearly there now. I was able to see how the registry values are actually accessed with the `reg query` command, and it was a good guess that the command was returning errors and falling through to the default setting.

When I tried calling `reg query` in a vanilla MSDOS `cmd` I got a message that it was not recognized.
Naturally you go look in the `PATH` variable at this point, and there I came across that nasty little space in the `C:\windows\system32\` entry. The space had been put there by accident on a previous edit, fancy that!

**Postscript**

In the process of writing this answer I stumbled across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9725056/1243435) SO answer which explains how it is the `PATH` variable that is the source of the problem! Just for the record, that SO answer actually points to a blog post [here](http://schrievkrom.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/error-cannot-determine-the-location-of-the-vs-common-tools-folder/)

You can see form the definition of the `:GetWindowsSdkDir` function that it looks in the registry at the `HKLM` values first, and if it does not find them it looks at the `HKCU` values. This suggests to me that Visual Studio 2008 Express does not use the registry entries in the `Wow6432Node` branches.

Answer (score 0):

If the blog post doesn't work. Try running the vsvars32.bat in your `<VS installdir>/Common7/Tools/vsvars32.bat` and then run devenv.exe (in the same environment).

Comment: In order to get that to work, you need to run DEVENV.EXE /USEENV. Useful workaround, but annoying, nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the brief below:

start-> run-> type in: regedit
now go to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SOFTWARE->Wow6432Node -> Microsoft ->Microsoft SDKs->Windows ->v8.0

Now on the right pane right click and New String Value as WindowsSDKDir. As its value type in:

C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\

That's it now build your solution again. N.B. 8.0 version is of mine you will find there yours.