# Switching VS2010 to use Windows 7.1 SDK

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, winapi

I've used VS2008 on my development machine for some years now, with windows SDK v7.1.

I've installed VS2010, and it's using the Windows SDK v7.0a, but I need it to use the Windows 7.1 SDK (which I had installed prior to installing VS2010).

When I run the Windows SDK 7.1 configuration tool, to switch the Windows SDK in use, the tool updates for VS2008, but not for VS2010.  The message it reports is:

```
"The Windows SDK Configuration Tool has successfully set Windows SDK version v7.1 as the current version for Visual Studio 2008"
```

The configuration tool is installed with the Windows 7.1 SDK and is found here:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Setup\WindowsSdkVer.exe"
```

VS2010 continues to use WSDK 7.0a, which extremely frustrating, as I need to do DirectShow development (so I need to build the baseclasses, which aren't released with 7.0a release of WSDK).

Would I be correct in assuming that it's not updating VS2010 settings because VS2010 wasn't installed at the time that I installed Windows 7.1 SDK?

Can I fix this manually, or should I uninstall Windows 7.1 SDK, then reinstall it?

Any other suggestions / workarounds for this?

Comment: related: [Windows SDK 7.1 + Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890504/), [WindowsSdkDir is not set correctly in Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599079/)

Answer (score 21):

For all those using *Visual Studio Command Prompt* I mention you have to modify `VCVarsQueryRegistry.bat` file (it's being called (indirectly) by `%VSINSTALLDIR%\VC\vcvarsall.bat`) which is placed in `%VSINSTALLDIR%\Common7\Tools` folder (typicaly `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools`) by modifying line 26 from

```
@for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%i in ('reg query "%1\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A" /v "InstallationFolder"') DO (
```

to

```
@for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%i in ('reg query "%1\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1" /v "InstallationFolder"') DO (
```

I wish someone from Microsoft explained why `WindowsSdkVer.exe` doesn't work for VS 2010...

Comment: It's better to modify it to `@for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%i in ('reg query "%1\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows" /v "CurrentInstallFolder"') DO (` so the version selected with `WindowsSdkVer.exe` is used.

Comment: Although, if you do as @ivan_pozdeev suggested, you should also edit the next line to check for `CurrentInstallFolder` instead of `InstallationFolder` or it will break.

Answer (score 19):

In project properties -> Configuration Properties -> General, set Platform Toolkit to WindowsSDK7.1 (or whatever version you want to use). Remember when you do this to select all configurations (release, debug, etc.) and all platforms (win32, x64, etc.) as appropriate. The documentation says you can set this option in the solution properties, but that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: More detailed instruction for this route are at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/06/15/windows-sdk-7-1.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this page guys. This is going to solve your problems -> [Building Applications that Use the Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660764.aspx)

Comment: The instructions on that page are not correct for VS2010.  There are comments which attempt to correct it, but those are wrong as well :)