# Visual C++ 2010 Express x64 assembly

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-construction, assembly, 64-bit

I was about to start learning x64 assembly using [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=guru397zg2g&list=FLhFj6qyNPRfheoDGPZHSIDg&index=3&feature=plpp_video) tutorial (series) but setting up Visual C++ Express just isn't working. I Have the x64 version installed and I even downloaded and installed [the windows 7 SDK.](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=3138)

However even after installing this package I still don't have the option to select the x64 platform in the configuraion manager (watch the tutorial to see what I mean, its at approx. 4:00)

I have tried restarting C++, but that doesn't work either. Whilst there are much sources on how to make the x64 compiler working they all explain the same steps which are the ones I did.

The only thing I can think of is either re-installing c++ or rebooting.

EDIT: Rebooting doesn't work.

EDIT 2: trying the [.net 4.0 Windows 7 SDK](http://%28http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8279%29) now... -> **doesn't enable the x64 compiler even though it is installed (if the installer is to be believed)**

Comment: Have you set VS to use the SDK as the platform toolset?

Comment: Probably not since I have no idea how to do that. Ill try to figure it out now. I guess I can set that under some sort of 'preferences' tab? Do you know where that is located?

Comment: Found it, but it doesn't help. I had the option to select v100 and v90 (v90 being the 2008VS Libraries). Swapping between those doesn't do the job..

Comment: No, it should say Windows SDK. Maybe this question helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095009/switching-vs2010-to-use-windows-7-1-sdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 Visual C++ **Express** Edition [does not include support for x64 compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hs24szh9.aspx).

Comment: It should be mentioned that one can still compile for x64 with the available tools, but not from within VS. Especially, one can not debug a 64-bit app inside VS, so another debugger is needed. I recommend [Visual Dux](http://www.duxcore.com/products.html) for that.

Comment: Weird, the guy in the tutorial (see my original post) has got it all working. Oh well, I moved to FASM anyway...no 64-bit for now ;)

Comment: VS2010 Express edition does not support x64 out-of-the-box, but with Windows 7 SDK and a patch (bugfix) installed, it works fine. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I also had problems compiling for x64 with my newly installed VS2010 Express, and Windows SDK installed. It turns out that Microsoft has found a bug with this configuration, and they have a patch that fixes this at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio//gg697159

VS2010 Express edition does not support x64 out-of-the-box, but with Windows 7 SDK and the above mentioned patch installed, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You must have the Windows SDK v ***7.1*** otherwise this won't work. I got burned by SDK 7 too.