# How to include Direct3D in a program?

Tags: c++, direct3d

I am learning Direct3D from directxtutorial.com. I am including it through a preprocessor directive in the code below.

```
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3dx11.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3dx10.lib")
```

This is not doing it, however. I am guessing it is because the library files aren't where its checking to find them. But could someone explain what's going on here? Thanks.
The error message is: "Intellisense: could not open source file"

Comment: First of all, make sure you have the Windows SDK and that it's added to your search directories.

Comment: How do you add the Windows SDK to the search directory?

Comment: There should be an option somewhere in your project settings (or overall settings). [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095009/switching-vs2010-to-use-windows-7-1-sdk) might help.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to download and install the Windows SDK from [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=8279).

Next, you'll need to configure your solution in Visual Studio to look for the appropriate files. This may be broken down in to two categories: **Adding the include paths** and **Linking the libraries**. Please take note of your Windows SDK directory. On my system, it is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\7.0A\`.

**Adding include paths**

Visual Studio comes pre-packed with a subset of the DirectX header `.h` files, but the complete collection is available in `WindowsSDKPath\Include`.

Add this path to your project's additional includes:

- Right click the project in the `Solution Explorer`, and choose `Properties` from the menu:
- Configure the dialog box to affect both Debug and Release builds:
  [image: Visual C++ Property Pages]

  - Select the first drop-down and choose `All Configurations`.
- From the tree on the left, choose `Configuration Properties | C/C++ | General`. This option will only appear if you have at least one `.c` or `.cpp` file in your project.
- In the `Additional Include Directories` box, add the path to your Windows SDK Includes, for example: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\7.0A\Include`.
- Press Apply.
- You're now ready to include the Direct 3D header files in your C++ code files, i.e. `#include <d3d11.h>`.

**Linking the libraries**

The Direct 3D libraries are contained in the `WindowsSDKPath\Lib` folder.

- From the tree on the left, choose `Configuration Properties | Linker | Input`.
- Tick the arrow on the drop-down of the `Additional Dependencies` field, choose `Edit...`
- In the pop-up dialog, add the full paths to each library, with each path on its own line, like so:
  [image: Linking Direct 3D Libraries]
- Press Okay, then press Apply or Okay.

Your project should now be configured to build Direct 3D Applications.

Comment: [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx) appears to be a current link to the Windows 8 SDK.