# What #include to use for using Vector3 in MSDN c++

Tags: c++, rotation, include, msdn, pragma

I am trying to implement [rotation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb281649(v=vs.85).aspx) in and the MSDN document has suggested everywhere to use [Vector3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms904560.aspx) structure to achieve this. However I get an error for both Vector3 and Quaternion saying `identifier not defined`

I understand this is because of not including the appropriate header file or not linking the proper library. I searched online but could not find which exact file to link and include.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781174/how-to-include-direct3d-in-a-program?

Comment: So we need to include directx headers and libraries for using vector3?

Comment: I'm don't really know, but links you've provided suggest that this is some part of Direct3D.