# Change Windows SDK version

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-xp

I need to build application that could run on windows XP. Is it possible set Visual C++ somehow to change Windows SDK version? How to get separate Windows XP SDK?

Seting  `Platform Toolset` to `Visual Studio 2012 - Windows XP (v110_xp)` didn't helped because I got error  `unresolved external symbol _CLSID_WICImagingFactory1` that I suppose is related to SDK non compatibility

This happens when I link MFC statically.

Comment: Did you try `#define _WIN_VER 0x0501` before the `#include <windows.h>` or other SDK header files?

Comment: `_CLSID_WICImagingFactory1`? Aren't you using COM library that doesn't support winxp?

Comment: This is the primary way you discover that you are writing code that cannot run on XP.  So it very much *did* help you keep out of trouble.  Fairly unclear how you got it, if you use the toolset setting properly so you'll target SDK v7.1 then only CLSID_WICImagingFactory is defined.  The Factory1 and Factory2 coclasses can only work in later Windows versions.

Comment: This happens when I link MFC statically.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/5734fbd0-a36a-4f76-9838-66c32ce4dfd5/error-unresolved-external-symbol-clsidwicimagingfactory1-with-vc11-visual-studio-2012?forum=windowswic

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095009/switching-vs2010-to-use-windows-7-1-sdk/