# Use older SDK's (Windows Sdk 7.1) in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, visual-studio-2013

Is there anyway to use an older Windows SDK (Windows SDK 7.1) for VS 2013. I need to make use of the ReBase functionality which was deprecated in Windows SDK 8. This is to support the legacy codebase which used ReBase.

Comment: is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6510511/815938) helpful?

Comment: It is a built-in feature for VS2013.  Project + Properties, General, "Platform Toolset" setting.  Change it to v120_xp and you'll automatically target 7.1.  That has more than one side-effect, it was actually meant to support targeting XP.  Move ahead by setting the /BASE linker option.  And just using the 7.1 version of rebase.exe until you get there.