# Visual studio can't find any standard c++ library file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I had vs2010 ultimate then I downloaded 2012 RC. It was working well at the beginning then at some point .net framework get messed up so I uninstalled both 2012 and 2010 (maybe I have manually deleted some folders too). Now I re-Installed vs2010 ultimate and the problem is none of the standard library files exist I figured so as I can't include any of them.

Any help how to fix that?

Comment: Do your standard C++ files reside in the PlatformSDK directory? In that case this can be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102689/windowssdkdir-is-not-set-correctly-in-visual-studio-2008

Answer (score 0):

That's a known problem with uninstaller of VS2012 RC/Beta. It will deregister the platform SDK, delete the folder, and even worse - would make changes for all previous VS versions. I am not sure what registry settings it changes (Around `$(VCInstallDir)`) - but it breaks it.

Only option is to find the relevant header, library and executable files, copy the path, and add it to your VC2010 (and previous, if any). You do it by VC++ Directories in Tools->Options, but that's not available for VC2010! So, you better specify the path in your project itself.

Tall order, I know, but it is like that - or you just re-install your OS. There is some "complete VS uninstallation" tool, but I couldn't find it now.

Comment: the thing is i cant find the SDK

Comment: Look into `\Program Files\MicrosoftSDKs`

Comment: Ye I did, But with a search in there i also couldn't find any of the standard C++ library files! Shouldn't they be there?

Comment: Have you checked the `Include` folder under it? Is it there? Which header-file(s) you are looking for?

Comment: Ye the include folder is availble in microsoft SDK->windows->v7.0A but this however are the headers that already appear in visual studios where they dont have "Any Standard Library files"

Comment: Can you name any one standard library file? I had the same problem, and solved it this way only.

Comment: vector.h  string.h  iostream.h

Comment: I thought so! It is <vector>, and <iostream> - WITHOUT .H extension!

Comment: well w/e those are them in in IDE i have it <vector> <iostream>

Comment: shouldnt these files be in the include folder as i cant find them there

Comment: Try searching in `\Program Files` or `\Program Files (x86)`

Comment: I dont belevie there is sdk folder in program files

Comment: and what do you do when you work with a later version of Visual Studio and want to use the 2010 platform toolset? Setting VC directories in 2010 isn't going to carry over to 2015, especially when 2015 wants a different version of the libraries, but 2010 version when using that platform toolset. There has to be registry keys somewhere or something.