# Visual Studio 2010 can't find cstddef

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm attempting to compile a C++ solution in VS 2010, but for some reason it can't locate the standard libraries.

I'm including as so:

```
#include <cstddef>
```

VS is returning an error as so:

```
main.cpp(10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cstddef': No such file or directory
```

However, I check my installation directory, and it's right where it's supposed to be (VC\include), and this directory is a part of my include directory list in the project settings ($(VCInstallDir)include).

Any ideas why this is happening, and how I can fix it?

Comment: Double check the spelling and make sure it's `cstddef` instead of something like  `cstdef`

Comment: Yeah, it is spelled correctly. Checked that first. :)

Answer (score -1):

Give a try using `#include <stddef.h>` instead.
However, MSVC 10 should have `<cstddef>`: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2b6eh9x3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

However, as @captain-obvlious pointed out this may require additional changes in your code..

Comment: That will pull everything into the global namespace instead of `std`.

Comment: @captain-obvlious: Correct! Added a note

Comment: Try with the solution posted here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a987f4fa-676f-4fda-ab69-2c6bcc2684c3/visual-studio-c-2012-standard-header-files-are-missing?forum=vssetup

Comment: No luck. Still throwing that error after uninstalling and re-installing.

Comment: Did you check if the import header is physically on your pc? do you have different MSVCs or SDKs installed? These may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11535236/2741329 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/1102718/2741329